# Реализация псевдозагрузки

Tags: python, python-3.x, loading

Не бейте за данный код, это как пример. Подскажите как можно реализовать данную псевдозагрузку? Не прошу готового кода, просто небольшая подсказка пойдёт

```
from time import *
from os import *
import random
per = 0.2
to = 0.5

def load():
    print("[..........]")
    sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
    system("clear")
    print("[#.........]")
    sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
    system("clear")
    print("[##........]")
    sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
    system("clear")
    print("[###.......]")
    sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
    system("clear")
    print("[####......]")
    sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
    system("clear")
    print("[#####.....]")
    sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
    system("clear")
    print("[#####.....]")
    sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
    system("clear")
    print("[######....]")
    sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
    system("clear")
    print("[#######...]")
    sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
    system("clear")
    print("[########..]")
    sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
    system("clear")
    print("[#########.]")
    sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
    system("clear")
    print("[##########]")
    sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
    print("LOADED")
    sleep(3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from time import *
from os import *
import random
per = 0.2
to = 0.5
pbar_len = 10


def load():
    for i in range(pbar_len+1):
        pbar = "#"*i + "."*(pbar_len-i)
        print("[" + pbar + "]")
        sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
        system("clear")
    print("LOADED")
```

Answer (score 2):

Как минимум можете использовать цикл для такого

```
...
print("[######....]")
sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def load(per=0.2, to=0.5):
    for i in range(10):
        system('clear')
        print('[' + '#' * i + '.' * (9 - i) + ']')
        sleep(random.uniform(per, to))
```